# Closing & then opening the serial port driver hangs Windows CE 6.0

Tags: windows-ce

Problem Iam facing closely related to the an old thread here:

[SerialPort.Open() freezes the system if data was received previously (Compact Framework)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/702524/serialport-open-freezes-the-system-if-data-was-received-previously-compact-fr)

1. Windows embedded CE 6.0 running on a x86 based SBC having 4 serial ports based on 16550 UART(part of the x86 SoC itself).
2. Connect a field device to a serial port that transmits at regular periods.
3. Open this serial port in a native app and keep reading data from the connected device.
   The native app uses the standard Win CE serial Communication API(CreateFile(), SetCommState(), ReadFile() etc.
4. Close this serial port. But serial data is still getting into the Windows CE system.
5. After some time try to open this serial port again. The whole  Windows CE system HANGS.

After debugging the Windows CE kernel the hangup seems to be happening because of an infinite loop created in the Serial PDD driver after the port re-open. Still debugging...

Anyone has come across this problem already?

P.S> The same hang problem happens even if .Net CF SerialPort class is used & the same steps are followed(using a C# SmartDevice Console type app built in VS2008).

Comment: Did you apply the fix suggested by Michael Burr in your other thread?

Comment: Iam using WIndows CE 6.0 R3 and the serial driver seems to be doing proper initialization of the 16550 block on Open call.

Comment: On the other hand during the hangup problem I see that there is a 'Character Timeout Indication' interrupt set in the IIR register indicating stale data in the Rx FIFO. But in this situation the 'Data Ready' bit is not set in the LSR register & so the driver gets confused and hangs itself during the Open process! Looks like a bug in the Serial PDD driver...